# How to select only 1 record from a group with a unique condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query. This query allows me to produce a list of children and their familymember contacts (contactpupilID).

```
select s.studentnr,pc.pupilid, pc.contactpupilid, p2.mainmail
from student s
join pupil p on p.id = s.pupilid
join pupilcontact pc on pc.pupilid = p.id
join pupil p2 on p2.id = pc.contactpupilid
where CURRENT_DATE between pc.validfrom and pc.validuntil
order by pc.pupilid
```

[image]

Each child can have 0 to 3 familycontacts (0 because no contact has been added during registration).
Each familycontact (contactpupilid) has an email field. However there are cases where all familycontacts have an email or 1 of them or none of them.

My list needs to select a child with a familycontact(contactpupilid) that has an email. The familycontact that is selected should be the one that has an email.

If none of the familycontacts have an email then it should select the 1st familycontact by default.

This is how it needs to look like

[image]

How would I complete this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "first record" because SQL tables are unordered.  I can assume you mean the one with the smallest `contactpupilid`.

What you have described is what `distinct on` does:

```
select distinct on (s.studentnr) s.studentnr, pc.pupilid, pc.contactpupilid, p2.mainmail
from student s join
     pupil p
     on p.id = s.pupilid join
     pupilcontact pc
     on pc.pupilid = p.id join
     pupil p2
     on p2.id = pc.contactpupilid
where CURRENT_DATE between pc.validfrom and pc.validuntil
order by s.studentnr, (p2.mainmail is not null) desc;
```

Comment: 1 record not first. I want to select 1 record!

Comment: can you believe the email address was never null. somehow it had some empty space characters in it. so i ordered it by char_length(p2.mainmail) desc. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Use ROW_NUMBER() window function in your query to rank the rows that contain an email first:

```
with cte as (
  select s.studentnr, pc.pupilid, pc.contactpupilid, p2.mainmail,
         row_number() over (partition by s.studentnr order by p2.mainmail is not null desc, pc.contactpupilid) rn
  from student s
  join pupil p on p.id = s.pupilid
  join pupilcontact pc on pc.pupilid = p.id
  join pupil p2 on p2.id = pc.contactpupilid
  where CURRENT_DATE between pc.validfrom and pc.validuntil
) 
select studentnr, pupilid, contactpupilid, mainmail
from cte
where rn = 1
order by pupilid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CTE like this

```
with temp as (
        select s.studentnr,pc.pupilid, pc.contactpupilid, p2.mainmail,row_number() over (partition by pupilid order by pupilid) as row_number
        from student s
        join pupil p on p.id = s.pupilid
        join pupilcontact pc on pc.pupilid = p.id
        join pupil p2 on p2.id = pc.contactpupilid
        where CURRENT_DATE between pc.validfrom and pc.validuntil
        order by pc.pupilid
)

select *
from temp
where row_number = 1
```

Comment: it produces a column called rownumber and its alway equal to 1, therefore its not selecting cases were the the 2nd familycontact who has an email doesnt get selected.

Comment: I dont want to select 1st record, i want only 1 record who holds an email address. If none are holding an email address, then it selects the 1st by default!